# Do the English words “dear”, “darling” etc share a root with Russian дорогой?

Tags: etymology, germanic-languages, russian

The Russian has an unclear etymology. Is there a phonological reason why it can’t be from a Germanic root? Wiktionary says the Germanic root (‘diurijaz‘) is also uncertain and might come from Latin “dūrus”; ‘hard’. All seems very unlikely.

Comment: I’d say they can’t easily both reflect the same root through direct inheritance, since the Germanic form _*deur(i)jaz_ (= Wiktionary’s _*diur(i)jaz_) has a diphthong (< PIE _*eu̯_), whereas the Balto-Slavic form _*dargaz_ has a monophthong (presumably < PIE _*o_). If we make up a root like _*dʰergʷʰ-_, it could _potentially_ work: thematic _*dʰorgʷʰ-ós_ would give PBS _*dargás_, and (somewhat unusual) _*dʰergʷʰ-i̯ós_ would likely give PG _**dergʷjaz_ > _*derwjaz_. Metathesis of this to _*deurjaz_ would not be unexpected. But I don’t think such a root is otherwise attested.

Comment: Thanks, I’m so inexpert in these sound changes that I must take your word for it, but I’m interested in your reasoning all the same. Is the assumption that Germanic diphthongs never become Slavic monophthongs?

Comment: Germanic isn’t a predecessor of Slavic, so Germanic diphthongs didn’t _become_ Slavic anything as such (except in loan words). They sometimes _correspond to_ Slavic monophthongs, but only in specific cases. The Indo-European diphthong _*eu̯_, which is what lies behind Germanic _*eu_ (or _*iu_), became _*jau_ in Balto-Slavic, not _*a_. Later on, the diphthong _*au_ was indeed monophthongised in Slavic (though not Baltic), but to long _*ū_ which doesn’t help here. Balto-Slavic _*a_ as reconstructed in _*dargás_ can only go back to Indo-European _*o_ or _*a_, not to any diphthongs.